# FileInfo CopyTo method throwing an IOException (.net)

Tags: c#

The CopyTo method of FileInfo class throws an IOException

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Data\Test.XML' because it is being used by another process.

Any ideas on why this should happen? I understand that copying a file just requires read access. So ideally even if the file is write protected or is opened by some other program the CopyTo should have no problem executing.

```
FileInfo copyFile = null;

//currentFile.FileInformation is of type FileInfo which is referring to the file for which a copy is being created. In this case it is C:\Data\Test.XML
System.IO.FileInfo file = new FileInfo(currentFile.FileInformation.FullName);

// Constructing name for the temporary copy of Test.XML
string newName = "Temp Copy of " + currentFile.FileInformation.Name;

//This is where I get the exception. The CopyTo fails...
copyFile = file.CopyTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentFile.FileInformation.DirectoryName, newName), true);

fs = System.IO.File.Open(copyFile.FullName, FileMode.Open);
```

**Also some important points to note :**

- I have write access to the folder to which I am trying to copy. This is happening with only certain files.
- The file for which I am trying to create a copy of is not Read-only.

Please let me know if I can provide you with any more details

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're correct that you only need read access to copy a file. The problem is that when a process opens a file, it gets to determain what access other processes are allowed. If that process opened the file without specifying FILE_SHARE_READ, no other process can open it for reading. Sometimes this is intentional on the part of the program's author. Most of the time I think program authors are using frameworks (or libraries) that hide details like this and they are ignorant of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another process might have specified the [`FILE_SHARE_READ`](http://FILE_SHARE_READ) mode when it opened the file, which would prevent you from even reading it.

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find that process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would like to know if it is possible to get the FILE_SHARE_READ status flag for the file. Is it possible programatically in C#?

Comment: @nick, do you mean determine if a given file was open with `FILE_SHARE_READ` by another process, or open a file with that flag in your own application?

Comment: Yes I would like to know if a given file was open with FILE_SHARE_READ.

Answer (score 2):

- Download [sysinternal's process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)
- put a breakpoint on File.CopyTo
- in process explorer, search for the file name, it will tell you which process got it open

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine what process is using the files you are trying to copy.